# Creating intermediate progress bar in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, progress-bar

I want to create an intermediate progress bar and this progress bar will be gone when my task is completed.

**Code:**

```
class MyZarinpal:AppCompatActivity() {




    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_myzarinpal)

        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_zarinpal)
        val progressBar: ProgressBar = progressBar1





        verificationpayment()

        button.setOnClickListener {

            //progress bar visiblity will be visible

            // do some back stuff // in here my payment()

            // and after loading complitliy the progress bar Visibility will be gone


        }

    }
    private fun mypayment() {

        val purchase = ZarinPal.getPurchase(this)

        val payment: PaymentRequest = ZarinPal.getPaymentRequest()


        payment.merchantID = getString(R.string.ZarinpalMerchantId)
        payment.amount = getString(R.string.increase_ten_thousend_toman).toLong()
        payment.isZarinGateEnable(true)
        payment.description = "your test payment"
        payment.setCallbackURL("return://myapp")


        purchase.startPayment(payment) { status, authority, paymentGatewayUri, intent ->

            if (status == 100) {

                startActivity(intent)

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "خطایی در برقراری ارتباط با درگاه رخ داده ، لطفا دوباره امتحان کنید",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()

            }
        }


    }

    private fun verificationpayment() {

        val text = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_status)

        val data: Uri? = intent.data

        val getpurchase = ZarinPal.getPurchase(this)
        getpurchase.verificationPayment(
            data
        ) { isPaymentSuccess, refID, paymentRequest ->

            if (isPaymentSuccess) {

                Toast.makeText(this, "افزایش موجودی شما با موفقیت انجام شد ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show()
                text.text = "شماره خرید شما :$refID"

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "در عملیات پرداخت خطایی رخ داده ، لطفا دوباره سعی کنید",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()

            }


        }
    }

}
```

I want that, when the button is clicked progress bar view is visible and as soon as the task (in here go to a web page ) is completed,the progress bar view is Gone .

**I tried this:**

```
button.setonclicklistener {

progressbar.visibility = View.visible

mypayment() // this is my task that will be run on background

// after loading the progress bar visibilty gone

progressbar.visibilty = View.Gone
```

But this code does not properly work and even does not show the progress bar. It directly goes to webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `progressBar.visibilty = View.GONE` right after you call `mypayment()`, but that function runs asynchronously. This means you hide the progress bar before you `mypayment()` finishes.
You should call `progressBar.visibilty = View.GONE` only after you get the callback from your API:

```
val getpurchase = ZarinPal.getPurchase(this)
    getpurchase.verificationPayment(
        data
    ) { isPaymentSuccess, refID, paymentRequest ->
        
        progressBar.visibilty = View.GONE

        if (isPaymentSuccess) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "افزایش موجودی شما با موفقیت انجام شد ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show()
            text.text = "شماره خرید شما :$refID"

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "در عملیات پرداخت خطایی رخ داده ، لطفا دوباره سعی کنید",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()

        }


    }
```

By the way, `mypayment()` is not a proper function name. You should name functions with an operation/action. For example, `mypayment()` should be `makePayment()`.